# Chrome on Android: 'click' event doesn't work but 'touchstart' does, but interferes with swiping

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, click

I have this scrollable list of elements that aren't responding to the 'click' event on Chrome for Android.  However, 'touchstart' does work.  The problem is, using 'touchstart' interferes with the swiping behavior of the list.  Is there an alternative to 'click' I could use?

Doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.items section', function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Does:

```
jQuery(document).on('touchstart', '.items section', function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about Javascript's DOM event handling?

Comment: I have just created this: http://jsbin.com/enavaj/1 and it shows it working, I think there is something else going on in your code, for example you might have another click handler on these elements that has preventDefault on them.  Please can you provide us with a more indepth example of it not working

Answer (score 0):

You might need to let us see the code that you are using before anyone can be of much help.
But your problem might be that touch start is bind to what ever the user does so you may need to unbind it.

Without seeing the code its hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: +1 agree, a simple example http://jsbin.com/enavaj/1 shows it works at a basic level